# Connect (login) to Alfresco with a simple Java class

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, alfresco

I tried to login into my alfresco which is deployed at : localhost:80/alfresco

This is what I've done so far :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebServiceFactory.setEndpointAddress("http://localhost:80/alfresco/api/");

    // Start the session
    AuthenticationUtils.startSession(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    try {

        //Work to do if the login works :S

    } finally {
      // End the session
      AuthenticationUtils.endSession();
    }
  }
```

This is what I get when I run the class :

```
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and   javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
Exception in thread "main" org.alfresco.webservice.util.WebServiceException: Error starting session.
at org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils.startSession(AuthenticationUtils.java:94)
at com.delta.logic.connect.Query1.main(Query1.java:53)
Caused by: (404)Introuvable
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.readFromSocket(HTTPSender.java:744)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:144)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
   at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
   at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
   at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
   at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
   at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
   at org.alfresco.webservice.authentication.AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub.startSession(AuthenticationServiceSoapBindingStub.java:187)
   at org.alfresco.webservice.util.AuthenticationUtils.startSession(AuthenticationUtils.java:79)
... 1 more
```

I'm really stuck here, HELP !

Comment: Are you sure you really want to be using the old WebServices support? For most things, you'll be better off using [CMIS](http://cmis.alfresco.com/) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to do this. If you go to /alfresco/service/index you'll see all the webservices that alfresco provide to his users.

What I did is simple. I got the URL for login webservice and used it like this :

```
public static String getAlfTicket(String _userName, String _password) {
String _ticket;
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

String JsonRequest = "{ \"username\": \"" + _userName + "\", \"password\": \"" + _password + "\" }";

HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(JsonRequest, headers);

person entity = restTemplate.postForObject("http://yourhost:port/alfresco/service/api/login", requestEntity,
    person.class);

// String path = entity.getHeaders().getLocation().getPath();

System.out.println(entity.getData().getTicket());
_ticket = entity.getData().getTicket();
return _ticket;
  }
```

You can notice that I used the restTemplate from Spring framework, but you are free to use what ever you want to get the response. The result of this function is a ticket that can be used later for other purpose.

Hope that helped !

Answer (score 3):

From [Alfresco Content Management Web Services](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Content_Management_Web_Services)

> Please also note that the endpoint for soap web services was moved for
>   alfresco 4.2.d. To make way for the public api 
>   now instead of being `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api` the soap
>   services resides at `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/soapapi`